# Fuzzy Logic for matching attributes for user records

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, fuzzy-logic, record-linkage

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for matching a set of user attributes, based on weight-ages (few attributes hold much priority compared to others) so as to have a handy recommendation engine based on the top most match from a fuzzy logic. What I find challenging is that the attributes are a mix of numbers & literals and also, there are a bunch of enumerations (A1, C2 etc) which IMO needs to be massaged before considering as an input for any string matching.

Any pointers to existing Python libraries or similar algorithms would help me.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/

Comment: and if you work with some decision making system you can see this amateur project: https://github.com/goodot/fuzzy-dm